# how to get the last weekday of the month in sqllite

Tags: sqlite

given a date in sqllite I would like to find the last weekday of the month.
for example, if given 11/17/2021 then the last weekday of the month is 11/30. however, if given 4/30/2022 which falls on a saturday then the last weekday of the month is 4/29/2022.

```
i try the following but this only gives me the last day of the month which can be either a weekend of weeday.
SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');
```

i am looking for the last weekday of the month given a specific date in sql lite.
can someone help me figure this out?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to calculate the day of the week for the end of the month, and adjust the result based off that value:

```
SELECT 
    CASE strftime('%w', date('now', 'start of month','+1 month','-1 day'))
        WHEN '0' THEN date('now', 'start of month','+1 month','-3 day')
        WHEN '6' THEN date('now', 'start of month','+1 month','-2 day')
        ELSE date('now', 'start of month','+1 month','-1 day') 
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will take a US formatted date (m/d/y) and output the last weekday in the month in the same US format:-

```
WITH
    cte_inputdate AS (SELECT '12/19/2022' /*<<<<<<<<<<< change as required */ AS inputdate),
    cte_convertdate AS 
        (SELECT 
            CASE
            /* m/d/yyyy */
            WHEN substr(inputdate,2,1) = '/' 
                AND substr(inputdate,4,1) = '/'
                THEN substr(inputdate,5,4)||'-0'||substr(inputdate,1,1)||'-0'||substr(inputdate,3,1)
            /* m/dd/yyyy */
            WHEN substr(inputdate,2,1) = '/'
                AND substr(inputdate,5,1) = '/'
                THEN substr(inputdate,6,4)||'-0'||substr(inputdate,1,1)||'-'||substr(inputdate,3,2)
            /* mm/d/yyyy */
            WHEN substr(inputdate,3,1) = '/'
                AND substr(inputdate,5,1) = '/'
                THEN substr(inputdate,6,4)||'-'||substr(inputdate,1,2)||'-0'||substr(inputdate,4,1)
            /* mm/dd/yyyy */    
            ELSE substr(inputdate,7,4)||'-'||substr(inputdate,1,2)||'-'||substr(inputdate,4,2)
            END AS inputdate
        FROM cte_inputdate
        ),
    cte_lastweekdayofmonth AS
        (SELECT *,
            CASE CAST(strftime('%w',inputdate,'start of month','+1 month','-1 day') AS INTEGER)
                WHEN 0 THEN date(inputdate,'start of month','+1 month','-3 day')
                WHEN 6 THEN date(inputdate,'start of month','+1 month','-2 day')
                ELSE date(inputdate,'start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
                END AS lastweekdayofmonth
        FROM cte_convertdate
        )
/* Extract lastweekdayofthemonth converting it to m/d/yyyy format */
SELECT
    CASE WHEN substr(lastweekdayofmonth,6,1) = '0' THEN substr(lastweekdayofmonth,7,1) ELSE substr(lastweekdayofmonth,6,2) END||'/'||
    CASE WHEN substr(lastweekdayofmonth,9,1) = '0' THEN substr(lastweekdayofmonth,10,1) ELSE substr(lastweekdayofmonth,9,2) END||'/'||
    substr(lastweekdayofmonth,1,4) AS lastweekdayofmonth
FROM cte_lastweekdayofmonth
;
```

e.g

- for **11/17/2021** then :-

[image]

- for **4/30/2022** then :-

[image]